Unable to add certificate to the "Add Licenses and Certifications" section of LinkedIn app from Android app
I have an Android application where I have the functionality to share the certificate directly to LinkedIn.
I am using the Add to Profile functionality mentioned in LinkedIn API documentation. When I try to create a certificate URL and go to the link, it takes me successfully to LinkedIn's Add Licenses and Certifications section with all the information pre filled.
But on pressing Save in LinkedIn's app on the Add Licenses and Certification section, I am getting the Something went wrong error.
I am using the below code for my Android app to accomplish the task:
 String certificationName = "Android";
    String organizationId = "1337";
    String issueYear = "2024";
    String issueMonth = "05";

    // Construct the LinkedIn URL with pre-filled certification details
    String linkedInUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME"
            + "&name=" + Uri.encode(certificationName)
            + "&organizationId=" + Uri.encode(organizationId)
            + "&issueYear=" + Uri.encode(issueYear)
            + "&issueMonth=" + Uri.encode(issueMonth);

    // Create an Intent to open the LinkedIn URL in a web browser
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(linkedInUrl));
    startActivity(intent);

An interesting thing to note here is that the certificate sharing link is working for iOS app and web. This is an error in Android's LinkedIn app in the implementation of this deep link. I am also sharing a screenshot of the error to help debug this issue.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue for Android? Or is there any other way through which I can accomplish my goal of sharing a user's certificate to LinkedIn in the Add Licenses and Certification section? I am not willing to achieve this through LinkedIn's API as it's not feasible for me to give the Login with LinkedIn feature to users just to share their certificates.

Screenshot of the error:

